# Error in regexp in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called product, with a variable email.

I would like to filter these values and store them into another data frame. Unfortunately, my code below is giving me an error "subset must be logical" ?

```
newdataframe<-subset(product,regexpr("/^([0-9]*)_",email))
```

Here I checking all email addresses that start with numbersequence and then underscore

Comment: ndf <- product[grepl("/^([0-9]*)_", product$email), ]?

Comment: Possibly `newdataframe <- product[grepl("^[0-9]+_", product$email),]`, but **your example is not reproducible.** Please include your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folks in the comments got there moments before I did, but I would also suggest:

```
product[grep("/^([0-9]*)_", product$email),]
```

The *reason* for your error is that regular expressions return the indices of the values that match the pattern. `subset()` on the other hand requires a logical, like

```
subset(product, email == "youremail@email.com")
```

Here's a reproducible example for the road:

```
> head(diamonds)
  carat       cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
1  0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326 3.95 3.98 2.43
2  0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326 3.89 3.84 2.31
3  0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327 4.05 4.07 2.31
4  0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334 4.20 4.23 2.63
5  0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335 4.34 4.35 2.75
6  0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336 3.94 3.96 2.48

> head(diamonds)[grep("E", head(diamonds)$color),]
  carat     cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
1  0.23   Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326 3.95 3.98 2.43
2  0.21 Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326 3.89 3.84 2.31
3  0.23    Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327 4.05 4.07 2.31

> subset(head(diamonds)[grep("E", head(diamonds)$color),])
  carat     cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
1  0.23   Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326 3.95 3.98 2.43
2  0.21 Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326 3.89 3.84 2.31
3  0.23    Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327 4.05 4.07 2.31
```